# XTransfer fail with error

Tags: parachain, xcm, xcmp, orml-xtokens

I am trying to move relay native currency back to relay chain.
But I got the error and can't figure out what is the problem?

Hey is my call, xcm configuration setting and error.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this error occurs in your sender chain, you could add `--log xcm=trace` when you run your node, and send the XCM again to get more logs about XCM for troubleshooting.

---

BTW, you seems to be using a little less weight, if the XCM is barriered by relay chain, you could try a bigger weight like 4000000000.

And in general, you should add these two barriers: `AllowKnownQueryResponses`, `AllowSubscriptionsFrom`, it would be useful when versions of XCM are inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

This could fail for a variety of reasons, as @Guantong mentioned, you are best looking at the logs of the collator to know the exact reason

Here is an [example](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fcollator.staging.imbue.network#/explorer/query/0xdf6f9e93d8bab00ebadec16e3d4ef6fa52835549280486bde786e854d1482849) transfer from our Imbue chain on Rococo

Also, [here](https://github.com/ImbueNetwork/imbue/blob/main/runtime/imbue-kusama/src/xcm_config.rs#L118) is the barriers we set

Re weight, we are using 5_000_000_000

Finally, documentation around XCM is not great right now because we are really early, the good news is all the teams are working on it.
I understand that it can be quite frustrating and time-consuming to get things right. What worked for us is setting up a unit test to help us understand the flow of an XCM transaction and its much faster to get an end to end test working than it is to go through trial and error on the polkadotjs UI

Here is an [example](https://github.com/ImbueNetwork/imbue/blob/main/runtime/integration-tests/src/xcm_transfers.rs#L288) of our XCM tests to the relay chain